# How convert html code to char in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

There are a lot of chars converted to HTML entities in input parameters.

To use it, I need to convert the HTML entities to chars to make it readable.

How I can do it in JavaScript (interesting in be-directional convertion)?

examples:

```
html-code | char
-----------------
  &#97;   |  a
```

Comment: How are your inputs ending up converted this way? Do you need to accept arbitrary HTML encoded characters, such as `&amp;`? Are you in a browser, or in node? There is nowhere near enough information to accurately answer this.

Comment: Any solution that uses `fromCharCode` to decode HTML entities is wrong in the general case. **Some** characters happen to encode to `&<ascii charcter code>;` but many do not.

Comment: @meagar Yes, `DOMParser` would be better in case all entities need to be supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the prefix ("&#") and suffix (";") and use [`String.fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode).

```js
function entityToChar(ent){
  return String.fromCharCode(ent.slice(2,-1));
}
console.log(entityToChar("&#97;"));
```

If you need to support arbitrary HTML entities, you can use the [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) API.

```js
function entityToChar(ent){
  return new DOMParser().parseFromString(ent, "text/html").documentElement.textContent;
}
console.log(entityToChar("&amp;"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try my code.

```js
var div=document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML="&#97;";
console.log(div.textContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_fromcharcode.asp

Use `fromCharCode()`. But you have to use only number. From your examples  `'&#97'` just cut `'&#'` out and `String.fromCharCode(97)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fromCharCode() for this

```js
var a = "&#97;";

var b = String.fromCharCode(a.slice(2,-1));

console.log(b);
```